# npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree in react

Tags: npm

I am doing a mern project in that I used the following command

**npm i react-router-dom axios react-paypal-express-checkout**

In that I faced the following error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"~0.14.8 || ^15.5.0" from react-paypal-express-checkout@1.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/react-paypal-express-checkout
npm ERR!   react-paypal-express-checkout@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\nahee\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.    

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\nahee\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-11T15_43_33_096Z-debug.log
```

And my package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "animal_feedmart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "cloudinary": "^1.23.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me to clear this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's the package.json of an express app, not a react app, `react-paypal-express-checkout` needs react as a dependency. Usually you don't mix client and server in a same package, since client files have to bundled before to be served.

Comment: Then can you please tell me what should I modify in my code

Comment: Create a separate folder for your react frontend. Go in it and type `npx create-react-app name-of-app`  Now you can install the packages you wanna use in your frontend build:
`npm i -s axios react-paypal-express-checkout`. Remember to add the entry "proxy: localhost:PORT" to your package.json where PORT is the port of your Express server, since in development you will have the client served on a webpack server, on a different port.

Answer (score 58):

I had a similar issue but the errors were after `npx create-react-app`.

I found a solution; you need to type `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`.

Answer (score 5):

```
npm i react-router-dom --force
```

OR

```
npm i anylibirary --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

actually this work for me

```
npm i axios --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

use "npm install --force"

Answer (score 0):

Just type this an press enter.

> npm config set legacy-peer-deps true

Answer (score -3):

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

npm ERR!

npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.1.0

npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0

npm ERR! node_modules/react

npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer react@"~0.14.8 || ^15.5.0" from react-paypal-express-checkout@1.0.5

npm ERR! node_modules/react-paypal-express-checkout

npm ERR!   react-paypal-express-checkout@"*" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

npm ERR!

npm ERR! See C:\Users\nahee\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\nahee\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-04-11T15_43_33_096Z-debug.log

if you ever faced this problem then

then you have to do

**npm install example --force**

at the place of example whatever you want to install

Comment: doing that crash your application, instead, use the `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`. copied from @Макс Волков comment above